# Excel operation inside MAX()

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max

I have data set like below. They are text strings.

```
1.2

1.3

1.4

2.0
```

I want to find the maximum. I have a European Excel so we use comma "," and not dot ".". 
I was thinking to do like this:

`=MAX(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4;".";","))`

When I omit nesting the functions it seems that `SUBSTITUTE()` does its job, `VALUE()` does its job, but `MAX()` seems to get a wrong input. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll either need to Array Enter the formula, which means confirming it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or add an `INDEX` function in your formula (which does not require that the formula be Array Entered):

```
=MAX(INDEX(--SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4;".";",");))
```

**EDIT**:

If there are blank cells or other strings in your data, then you will need to use this ***array formula*** (confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=MAX(IFERROR(--SUBSTITUTE(A1:A7;".";",");0))
```

Comment: the proposed formula also yields "#VALUE!". As well does my proposal when entered as array. Doesn't the index function return 1 value from the array? How can the MAX() function then find a maximum?

Comment: @user3115817 I can verify that given your provided sample data, this formula produces the correct result of `2`.  If you are getting a value error, please provide more relevant sample data.  As for how the Index function works, it creates an array, and can return that entire array if no additional arguments are provided (note there is nothing after the last `;` in the formula, meaning those Index arguments were omitted).

Comment: @user3115817 My guess is that the #Value! error is a result of a failed attempt at trying to convert a string into a number.  That would cause the `--` or `Value()` to give a `#VALUE!` return error, which is what would cause the rest of the formula to ultimately give that same error.  This is a problem with the source data, not the formula.  You will definitely need to provide more representative sample data.

Comment: @user3115817 For example, a blank cell in your data could cause this issue.

Comment: @user3115817 I have edited my answer to account for blank cells or other strings in the data.

Comment: Thank you. now it works. It was because I had an blank cell in my dataset. Your help is much appreciated.